# Web Socket and non blocking mode

Tags: java

If we set a Socket Channel configureBlocking to false, then will the connection automatically  become duplex mode?  What I am trying to say, in that case, can the server then push the data to client browser asynchronously?  Do I need to program this behaviour manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ServerSocketChannel and SocketChannel configureBlocking method inherit from the AbstractSelectableChannel class.  The configureBlocking method returns a SelectableChannel object.

Here is a snippet from the documentation about a SelectableChannel object:

> Blocking mode
>
> A selectable channel is either in blocking mode or in non-blocking mode. In blocking mode, every I/O operation invoked upon the channel will block until it completes. In non-blocking mode an I/O operation will never block and may transfer fewer bytes than were requested or possibly no bytes at all. The blocking mode of a selectable channel may be determined by invoking its isBlocking method.
>
> Newly-created selectable channels are always in blocking mode. Non-blocking mode is most useful in conjunction with selector-based multiplexing. A channel must be placed into non-blocking mode before being registered with a selector, and may not be returned to blocking mode until it has been deregistered.

Newly created selectable channels are always in blocking mode, so **yes** you must explicitly invoke configureBlocking(false) if you want non-blocking duplex mode.

Here are a list of Javadocs that you may find helpful:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ServerSocketChannel.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SelectableChannel.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/spi/AbstractSelectableChannel.html#configureBlocking(boolean)

Comment: In short, one have to edit the program to use Selectable. It is not as simple as flipping a switch.